# Svn revert to old revision and commit in Windows

Tags: svn

I reload an old version of the project, (3 revision back, lets say 1 to the old and 4 is the newest one). I need to make some changes in version 1 and I need to commit it. And from now on I want to continue with version 1. But svn do not allow me to do.

I also need to keep the versions 2, 3 and 4.

I thought that if I make some changes on version 1 and commit it I get the version 5. But I think there is branch issues about it, but it is really complicated I cannot find the solution from the internet.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: It makes sense to write which client you use for working with SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described [in the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo). You need to perform a "reverse merge" to undo the changes made since revision 1, commit that, then continue.

`svn merge -r 4:1 URL`

Or you could do it in steps by revision

```
svn merge -c -4 URL
svn merge -c -3 URL
svn merge -c -2 URL
```

Comment: A) It's *command* prompt, not "comment". B) No one "right clicks to go to SVN" - are you referring to using TortoiseSVN? TSVN has its own merging interface that will help you with these steps. Also, as of 1.7 the command-line client is installed with TSVN by default, so you can use that as well.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I am using TSVN. I just did not understand the solution, what should be done, in plain English.

Comment: The TSVN Merge dialog will walk you through it.